# Percentage calculation keeps returning 0

Tags: java

What I am trying to achieve is a grading system for a test but the variable `percentGrade` keeps returning 0 if there are wrong answers.

Code for reference :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Result
{
    private Test test;
    private ArrayList<String> correctAnswers;

    public Result()
    {
        this.correctAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
   public void addTest(Test test) {
       this.test = test;
   }

   public Test getTest() {
       if(this.test != null) {
           return this.test;
        }     
        return null;   
   }
   
   public void addcorrectAnswers(String correctAnswers) {
       this.correctAnswers.add(correctAnswers);
   }
   
   public ArrayList<String> getCorrectAnswers() {
       return this.correctAnswers;
   }
   
   public String getGrade() {
           
        int counter = 0;
        
        for(String gradingAnswers : this.correctAnswers) {
            for(String answersTest : this.test.getAnswers()) {
                if(answersTest == gradingAnswers) {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(this.test.getAnswers().size() > 0){
            double percentGrade = (counter / this.correctAnswers.size()) * 100; //ISSUE IS HERE 
            if(percentGrade > 55) {
                return "Your score is " + percentGrade + "% ." + " You PASSED!!";
            }else if(percentGrade <= 55){
                return "Your score is " + percentGrade + "% ." + " You FAILED!!"; 
            }else {
                return "Could not return score !";
            }
       }
        return "Could not return answers or calculate";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

counter and this.correctAnswers.size() are both integers, so '/' is an integer operator.
Try

```
   double percentGrade = ((float)counter / this.correctAnswers.size()) * 100;
```

to force a float division.

If you need control precision, I would suggest using BigDecimal class and its .divide() method.

```
        BigDecimal.valueOf(counter ).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(size),4, RoundingMode.CEILING).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(100));
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my issue and also to round the number since it was a bit too big I did ```import java.lang.Math;``` and then ```double percentGrade = Math.round(((double)counter / this.correctAnswers.size()) * 100);```

Answer (score 1):

Casting to float will ensure you use float division instead of int division. Int division is usually the wrong choice for division that involves higher precision.

`double percentGrade = ((float)counter / this.correctAnswers.size()) * 100; //ISSUE IS HERE  if(percentGrade > 55)`